# Creating P-I-P video while also adding transparency to the In-Picture?

Tags: ffmpeg

Starting with two clips of the same format, scale, etc...
I am trying to use ffmpeg to add transparency to one of them while it is scaled down and used as an overlay for a translucent picture-in-picture.

In simplest terms, I am trying to bring these two features together.

```
 ffmpeg -i FullScreenVidio.mp4 -i PictureWindow.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2.15:ih/2.15 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=25:25" -profile:v main -level 3.1 -b:v 440k -ar 44100 -ab 128k -s 1920x1080 Result.mp4 

=vf eq=brightness=0.25:contrast=1.5:saturation=1.5
```

I know it is possible, since I was able to get a test to work using a 3rd party program that operates by passing commands to ffmpeg.
My needs are more specific than that app allows.

Comment: the ```pip``` tag you used.. read the description of it. It dosn't say what you think (or it is? I am not familiar with the framework you are using and this is why I don't remove the tag myself)

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the correct usage.  I didn't see the descriptor before I posted.
Picture-In-Picture is the PIP I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*add transparency to one of them while it is scaled down and used as an overlay for a translucent picture-in-picture*

For this, basic filter syntax is

`-filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2.15:-1,format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.4 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=25:25"`

The colorchannelmixer filter here sets the opacity of PictureWindow.mp4 to 40%.

Comment: I used it just as you provided, ffmpeg processes it - but the result has no translucency at all.

Comment: I was coming back to post a modification that let it work for this purpose.
 
`ffmpeg -i WindoClip.mp4 -i BackClip.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.8,scale=iw/2.15:ih/2.15 [pip]; [1][pip] overlay=25:25" -s 1920x1080 -v <encoding args> Result.mp4`

Comment: Converting it to yuva444p will lead to an extra conversion to rgba internally.